# Get position of insertion / point (not of the mouse pointer)

Tags: windows, powershell

I'd like to get the position of the caret, also known as insertion point or cursor, on the screen, as opposed to the position of the mouse pointer. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Which software are you using? What data content? What have you tried? What results have you had? You haven't given us anything to work with here.

Comment: That info is depends on the context.  For example, if you are working with controls in WinForms, there may be a method built into the control, or a way to use the control's handle ask Windows for that info.  Please provide more info: Are you building a GUI in PowerShell?  If so, some details on what it is (WinForms, WPF, other?) and what type is the control that has the text cursor.  Are you trying to access an external application? Some details?